# Does geometric quantization work for second quantization?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, differential-geometry, second-quantization, quantization

I have been studying geometric quantization, and was wondering if a similar method could be employed for the second quantization. I imagine such a setup would involve “going up a level;” our “phase space” would consist of our potential and conjugate momentum fields, which would allow the construction of a symplectic manifold (the costa gent bundle) with 2-form given by $\omega=\sum\limits_\nu\pi^\nu\wedge A^\nu$. From here, one could construct a bundle structure (or something of the sort) and then use the typical method of geometric quantization (prequantization and polarization). However, I see a few problems with this. First of all, we are not considering our Lagrangian at all, and our “phase space” is dependent on the configuration space of the fields constituting it. Are these hurdles enough to render geometric quantization as frivolous for second quantization? If not, is the method I described a sufficient way of doing so, or is there another way to geometrically quantize quantum fields?